# Formulario que no se envía si el correo del remitente es de google

Tags: php, formularios

Llevo un par de días buscándole la lógica a mi problema pero por más que lo intento no deja de ser un misterio para mi.

Tengo un formulario en el **index.html** que tiene el campo Nombre, Apellidos, E-mail y texto; éste envía por el método POST los datos a **conexion.php**, la cual envía un e-mail con los referidos campos.

El misterio está en que al rellenar el formulario, en el campo "E-mail" si pongo un correo que contenga @google.com, @google.es, @yahoo.com, @yahoo.es el correo con el formulario no llega nunca ni da error en php, sé que tiene que estár relacionado con esta línea:

```
$headers = "From:" . $correo . "\r\n";
```

porque si la suprimo si que llegan sin problemas, pero en la bandeja del cliente de correo no aparece el correo del remitente. Es extraño porque si pongo desde el formulario correos de @hotmail.com, incluso inventados tipo @ejemplo.com u @meloinvento.com, los correos llegan siempre.

Alguien sabría decirme por qué ocurre ésto? Os paso el código del formulario y del php

### Formulario

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required" data-error="El nombre es requerido.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" required="required" data-error="Los apellidos son requeridos.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" data-error="Se requiere un e-mail válido.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea id="form_message" name="texto" class="form-control" placeholder="Dinos como te podemos ayudar..." rows="4" required="required" data-error="Por favor escriba un mensaje"></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Enviar mensaje">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted">

                                    </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$to = "info@midominio.com";
$subject = "Mensaje desde midominio.es";
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$correo = $_POST['email'];
$contenido = $_POST['texto'];

$headers = "From:" . $correo . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: correo@ejemplo\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

$mensaje = "Nombre: " . $nombre . " " . $apellidos . "\r\n";
$mensaje .= " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Correo: " . $correo . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: \r\n\r\n" . $contenido . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

mail($to, $subject, $mensaje, $headers);
header("Location:index.html");
?>
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: puede que este llegando  a la carpeta spam intenta cambiado esto `$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $correo . "\r\n"; ` o utilizando [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) que esta mas completa que la funcion `mail` y esta ultima no siempre viene habilitada en todos los hosting!

Comment: Me los estaba mandando al SPAM y no me había dado cuenta!!! Mil gracias